# Lexicographical sort with locale settings

Tags: c++, sorting, locale

How can I achieve the correct sorting?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

inline bool sort_string_swiss(std::string const& a, std::string const& b){
    return std::use_facet<std::collate<char> >(std::locale("fr_CH.UTF-8")).compare(&a[0], &a[0] + a.size(), &b[0], &b[0] + b.size())<0;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> list{"De rien", "Décider","Devant"};
    std::cout<<"Correct: ";
    for(auto const& l:list){ std::cout<<l<<" "; } //outputs De rien Décider Devant

    std::sort(list.begin(),list.end(),sort_string_swiss);
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"Not correct: ";
    for(auto const& l:list){ std::cout<<l<<" "; } //outputs Décider De rien Devant

    std::sort(list.begin(),list.end());
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"Not correct: ";
    for(auto const& l:list){ std::cout<<l<<" "; } //outputs De rien Devant Décider
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

The code given above does not give a correct output. I want to achieve lexicographic sorting with special characters correctly handled (as given when the list is initialized). I looked at different posts but none seem to fit my requirements. I looked at [the Unicode collation documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Introduction) but it is too complicated.

## Edit

After the suggestion of @darune, I added

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_CH.UTF-8");
```

and

```
inline bool sort_string_strcoll(std::string const& a, std::string const& b){
    return std::strcoll(&a[0],&b[0])<0;
}
```

but

```
    std::sort(list.begin(),list.end(),sort_string_strcoll);
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"Not correct: ";
    for(auto const& l:list){ std::cout<<l<<" "; } //outputs Décider De rien Devant
```

Comment: Have you tried `std::strcoll` with `std::setlocale` ? might help debugging, even if you don't want to set locale globally.

Comment: I don't mind setting locale globally... I could try that...

Comment: Ok, then you should probably check out https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/operator() as well

Comment: Looking at your post again, it is not at all obviouse which you think is the correct sorting ?

Comment: Well, the first list I give... I'll precise that!

Comment: Your expected ordering doesn't make sense `"De...", "Dé...", "De..."`.

Comment: In fact comparative function compares bytes, not characters. So if you sure that you chars are UNICODE, i.e. UTF-(8|16LE|16BE|32LE|32BE) you can compare them without any locale at all.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin why? the third caracter is " " for "De rien" while it is a letter fot the two others... And I want "é" to be counted as a "regular" letter as ordered in the french dictionnary...

Comment: @VictorGubin okay but then it may not order them as in the dictionnary!? or am I wrong?

Comment: @PinkFloyd you can code your own algorithm, or use existing from  [IBM ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings) - International Components for UNICODE

Comment: Does _e_ come before _é_ or after?

Comment: e is `65`  from [Basic Latin 20—7F](https://unicode-table.com/en/) when `é` `233` is from  [Latin-1 Supplement 80—FF](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/latin-1-supplement/). Off case `65  < 233` and `strcmp, memcmp etc` (std::char_traits<char>::compare) will work wrong. So IBM ICU can help with this, std::locale is something more complicated, as well as there is no any guaranty that standard library implement this string compare correctly (mind be but mind be not, depending on the end user system etc), unlike ICU.

Comment: @VictorGubin I think you should put that as the answer.